# Adding Trim to Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression

Tags: linq, dynamic, criteria

I got a Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression which represents a property in an object. I am dynamically creating a condition on a list of objects, but this property may have trailing spaces.

I need to add a Trim function to this MemberExpression so when I execute the condition it is evaluated correctly.

Thanks

JP

Comment: What is so special with `Trim` compared to any other function? Isn't this simple `Expression.Call(...`. If you show some code, we could better understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.

```
// put your expression to retrieve the member here.  Assumes the member is a string!
MemberExpression memberExpr = null; 

// now wrap the member expression in a call to TrimEnd
var emptyCharArrayExpr = Expression.Constant(new char[0]);
var stringTrimEndMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("TrimEnd");
var resultingExpr = Expression.Call(memberExpr, stringTrimEndMethod, emptyCharArrayExpr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The resultingExpr is of type MethodCallExpression.
How can I convert it to a MemberExpression?

Comment: @Jean-PierreScerri How can I convert Banana to an Apple? `MemberExpression` stands for property or field, after calling `Trim` it's no more property or field, but a result of a method call, hence `MethodCallExpression`.

Comment: Why does TrimEnd work find and Trim does not.
It throws an exception, `Ambiguous match found`.

Comment: @JPS - It's because Trim has two overloads, so instead of using GetMethod you'd have to use GetMethods and filter down to the one you want.

ps. I used TrimEnd as you said you wanted to remove trailing spaces.